# Android align multiple TextView-s in line

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, alignment, android-relativelayout

i am trying to align multiple (variable) textviews in one line. It should look like this:

```
- Textview1 | Textview2 | TextView3
```

Since the textviews vary regarding length  I am having a problem aligning them properly(the only thing I know is that Textview1 will be the shortest one).

Here is my code (it is placed inside a Linear Layout):

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/persondetails_names_horizontal_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/persondetails_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:text=" Title "
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/persondetails_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" Name "
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_big"
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/persondetails_title"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/persondetails_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/persondetails_surname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/persondetails_name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/persondetails_name"
                android:text=" Surname " />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Now, as long as these 3 Textviews fill out one line on the screen everything is OK, but as soon as one of them gets bigger I get some problems. For example, when I put the `surname` field very long, it pushes the other 2 views out of the screen (they are not visible) and takes all the space (but just one line!).

What I want is that these views are aligned to the right side, each of them to the right of the previous one, and when it is needed to linebreak into a new line (no mather which textview it is) and in the new line the following textviews should align to the right of it.

So what do I need to change in my code, so that these Textviews are aligned next to each other, and moved properly when one of them is getting bigger ?

Thank you

This is how I implemented Elltz suggestions:

```
     <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/persondetails_namen_horizontal_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/persondetails_wert_titel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/persondetails_wert_vorname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/persondetails_text_vorname"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text=" "
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:overScrollMode="always"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/persondetails_wert_nachname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/persondetails_text_vorname"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text=" "
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:overScrollMode="always"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

But still not working. Actually I removed the "singleLine=true" because in case when one of the 3 textviews gets too long I need it break (don't have a problem with breaking).

Regarding breaking, I want every textview to take as muche space as it needs, the only thing is that all the other views shoud be moved properly.

The property "single line" cannot be right because it is possible that one of these views gets too long for one line, but I have tested it with single line and without:

a) with "singleline=true"[image]

b) without "singleline=true" [image]

In bothe cases I get a wrong output, but case 2 is closer to what I want. But if you look at it you will see that textview2 is being pushed and it breakes in its bounds but not on the entire lenght. Textview 3 takes the most space. But what i want is that every view is fully streched and if needed breaked into new line (textview1 is this "Mag.")

This is how I would like it to look like:

[image]

Comment: sorry I didn't see it. Where did you post your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the relative layout to a linear layout and then set the orientation to horizontal something like this.

```
        <LinearLayout:id="@+id/persondetails_names_horizontal_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/persondetails_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:text=" Title "
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/persondetails_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Name "
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_big"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/persondetails_surname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Surname " />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try and do a LinearLayout and weight each element.

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/persondetails_names_horizontal_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/persondetails_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:text=" Title "
            android:layout_weight= "1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/persondetails_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Name "
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_big"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_weight= "1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/persondetails_surname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight= "1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text=" Surname " />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Am I right in saying that you need to put a weight sum of 3 on the linear layout if you are setting the weight?

Comment: actually, before i used relative layout i used linear layout, the exact way you are describing. The problem there is that every textview has its own width (described with the "weight" attribute) and in case it is too long it does not push further to the right, it makes a new line in that space that it is occupying. For example, if Textview2 is too long, it won't push textview3 further to the right, but it will break to a new line in its own space (hope i described that so it is understandable).

Comment: @andy Joyce, no you don't have to put the sum of weights to 3. All the weights that you put are being summed up and the screen is being horizontally/vertically divided by that number, and then every view is getting their part regarding of the weight they have. For example, if the sum of all weights is 10, then te width of the screen is being divided by then, and if one view has a weight os 2, it will get 2/10 width of the screen

Answer (score 0):

To answer why your code line is giving you that problems is a `RelativeLayout` positions its `View`s relative to each other, a `View` will need another `View` to be layed out if not the parent itself. So `TextView` 1 is positioned to the left of `TextView` 2 when `TextView` two gets bigger since its to the left it will be to the left but not on screen layout or space get it?

To answer you

`TextView` 1 will be the shortest Using the `LinearLayout` Approach with `weightsum` and `weight` tweak it this way first set the `weightsum` to two on the `LinearLayout` and the two *i am going to be long* `TextView`s give them a width of `0dp` and weight `1` each the shortest `TextView` will have `wrap_content` as `width` and that's all life's is good.  now the two long `TextView`s will calculate their sizes and the rest will be left for the shorter one. I do not not specifically how you want your `TextView` to long in terms of straight horizontal line but after you have done that you can add these elements to your `TextView` in xml or you could do it in java to ensure your straight lined `TextView`s

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:overScrollMode="always"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:singleLine="true"
```

EDIT

this is what i mean

```
int width = getWindow().getDecorView().getMeasuredWidth();
//i am getting the overal width of the screen
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(width), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//toast it
    for(int i =0; i < ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.l)).getChildCount(); i++){
        //looping through the parent container
        TextView child = (TextView) ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.l)).getChildAt(i);
        child.setSelected(true);
        child.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        child.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
        child.setSingleLine(true);
        if(i+1 == 3){ //the last textview
            child.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.l)).getChildAt(1).getRight(), 
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }else{ // the first two take 1/3 of the width of the screen
            child.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width/3, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Elitz, for the sake of readability I have answered you with a "new answer"