# Android - ScrollView four button in each lines xml

Tags: android, android-xml

how to put four images in each lines and vertical scrolling, here is my code putting 1 item in each line and vertical scroll-er also working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg_main"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout" > 


   <ScrollView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="center" >

     <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearMainLayoutId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:weightSum="2">


        <ImageButton
   android:layout_width="125dp"
   android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_alphabet"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" 
            android:id="@+id/alphabetId"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageButton
   android:layout_width="125dp"
   android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_alphabet"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" 
            android:id="@+id/alphabetId1"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageButton
   android:layout_width="125dp"
   android:layout_height="125dp"
                 android:src="@drawable/img_alphabet"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" 
            android:id="@+id/alphabetId2"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>     
                       <ImageButton
   android:layout_width="125dp"
   android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_alphabet"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" 
            android:id="@+id/alphabetId3"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageButton
  android:layout_width="125dp"
  android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_alphabet"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" 
            android:id="@+id/alphabetId4"
            android:layout_weight="1"/> 
                                                 <ImageButton
 android:layout_width="125dp"
 android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_alphabet"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" 
            android:id="@+id/alphabetId5"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageButton
     android:layout_width="125dp"
     android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_alphabet"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" 
            android:id="@+id/alphabetId6"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>    
    </LinearLayout>


     </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

the above code is worked fine just want to put four items in every-lines regardless of items it could be in x nos.

Comment: you want your item to in a horinzontal line regardless of their width ? [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290626/android-align-multiple-textview-s-in-line/30301873#30301873)

Comment: i done horizontal, but it showing in straight line but i want break line in every four image show @Elltz

Comment: give me a screen shot i do not get you, from what i understood i will say put every for imageviews in a linearlayout do not put all in one viewgroup because you have two nested linearlayout so repeat the second one

Comment: if i will do horizontal view it give me left to right and right to left scrolling in a single line... how to restrict 4 items per line.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the layouts in /res/layout are applied to both portrait and landscape.

If you have for example

```
/res/layout/main.xml
```

you can add a new folder /res/layout-land, copy main.xml into it and make the needed adjustments.